# CygWin How to create a Window with GNU C++ that can be move without a X-Server Window Manager

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, xserver

like the Subject of the Topic said:

- CygWin for Windows comes with a X-Server port for Windows
- How can I create a "moveable" Window, with the X-Server
  functions that are available when you (me) programming with
  the GNU C++ Compiler
- I have already programming with Qt5 but I would do this
  with built-in Functions from the X-Server without the useing
  of a Window Manager

Thanks for reading, and Helping Feedback

- I already able to create a Window with Qt5 Framework
  but this Framework need a huge amount of space because the
  big libraries that come with
- I expecting a small Example without using any Framework,
  only the X-Server Functions that are available for Cygwin
  X-Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the [[YouTube]:
Future Tech Labs - X11 Tutorials - 1 - Creating a Simple Window](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2F_Lif4KGA) tutorial, and came up with the following (dummy) example.

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>


int main()
{
    Display *pd = NULL;
    if ((pd = XOpenDisplay((char*)NULL)) == NULL) {
        printf("XOpenDisplay error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int scr = DefaultScreen(pd);
    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(pd, RootWindow(pd, scr),
        100, 100, 320, 200, 15, BlackPixel(pd, scr), WhitePixel(pd, scr));
    XSetStandardProperties(pd, win, "Cygwin X q075977479", "q075977479", None, NULL, 0, NULL);
    XMapWindow(pd, win);

    XEvent ev;

    while (XNextEvent(pd, &ev) == 0) {
    }

    XUnmapWindow(pd, win);
    XDestroyWindow(pd, win);
    XCloseDisplay(pd);

    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075977479]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> uname -a
> CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 cfati-5510-0 3.4.6-1.x86_64 2023-02-14 13:23 UTC x86_64 Cygwin
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc main00.c -o main00.exe -lX11
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.c  main00.exe
> [064bit prompt]> DISPLAY=:0 ./main00.exe
> ```

And the window:

[image: Img0]

Might also want to check:

- [[X]: Xlib - C Language X Interface](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html) - *X* *API*
- [[Cygwin]: Chapter 3. Using Cygwin/X](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html) - *Cygwin* specifics

Comment: Thank You for providing a Source Text, and the Bonus as Video.